# How can you add external dependencies to bazel

Tags: android, gradle, tensorflow, bazel

I am a student and currently working on a project where I am trying to connect my game that which I have created with Android Studio. A neural network has also been made with Tensorflow which is going to be used for the android game.

The problem is that Android Studio uses a build tool which is called Gradle and Tensorflow uses Bazel. To solve this problem I have been trying to build my android game with Bazel but I am stuck at the part where I have to add the used external dependencies. For the game I use the following dependencies:

- Appcompat
- Support
- Percent

Which supposedly should come with the android support repository.

I have looked at http://www.bazel.io/docs/external.html and several other sources  but I still do not understand how I can add the dependensies. Could someone provide me with an example how to do it with for example appcompat and what I have to do to make it work? Or is there another way which would be easier?

EDIT: I have have been succesful in building the android example of Tensorflow but this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android
But it doesn't include dependensies which I am using.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the Makefile support we just added for Android:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/makefile

It's still very experimental (and fiddly), but should let you build a static library that you can more easily use in your gradle project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but for now I have removed the external dependencies. I am now encountering a new problem when building with Bazel I get the message that it cannot find the R package. However I am able to succesfully build it with Gradle in Android Studio. Do you perhaps know how to resolve this? In the past when I had this problem in Android Studio I could fix it by cleaning and rebuilding the project. But this seems to not work for Bazel.

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind I resolved my issues, after removing the depensies I checked the WORKSPACE file. It seems I didn't set the package correctly, my bad.

Comment: Could you provide ? I'm trying to solve the same issue. And Bazel 0.3.0 does not seem to pick the external dependencies (android, tensorflow..).